# jQuery - if div overlaps adjust css top value

Tags: jquery

I have many anchor tags where its name dynamically generating, but it is getting overlapped.

How can I increase css (top value to 20px) to second lable if two labels overlaps?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-div">
        <div class="social-links">
            <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Facebook"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-20.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Twitter"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-20.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Youtube"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/youtube_circle_color-20.png" alt="Youtube" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Linkedin"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-20.png" alt="Linkedin" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{margin:50px auto;}
.main-div{width:600px;margin:auto;border:1px solid #ccc;font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;padding:120px 20px 10px 20px;background:#f5f5f5;}
.main-div a{display:inline-block;position:relative;}
.main-div a .popup-text{display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:-22px;left:0;background:#ccc;padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid #ffffff;}
.popup-text:before {content: "";display: block;background: red;width: 1px;height: 20px;float: left;margin: 0;position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 0px;height: 34px;}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.main-div').find('a').each(function() {
  var popupText = $(this).attr('data-social');
  $(this).append('<div class="popup-text">'+popupText+'</div>');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mh1p7b03/)

**Overlapped**

[image]

**Expecting**

[image]

Comment: Please, post the CSS and Html in the question, not only a link.

Comment: @Kzrystof, sorry for that.. updated now... can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

Please check my solution. You have to add the more dynamic class for a set `:before` pseudo and a top position has to set dynamically.

**I have edited this post for the dynamic width of Icon.** Note that it does not work for responsive layout.

```js
var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
    
var counter=0
$('.main-div').find('a').each(function(i) {
  var popupText = $(this).attr('data-social');
  $(this).append('<div class="popup-text popup-text-'+i+'" style="top:-'+(counter+1)*22+'px">'+popupText+'</div>');
  
  var beforeHeight=34+(counter*22);
  newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(".popup-text-"+i+":before{height:"+beforeHeight+"px;}"));
 document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
  if($(this).outerWidth() < ($('.popup-text',$(this)).outerWidth())){
    counter++;
  }
});
```

```css
body{margin:50px auto;}
.main-div{width:600px;margin:auto;border:1px solid #ccc;font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;padding:120px 20px 10px 20px;background:#f5f5f5;}
.main-div a{display:inline-block;position:relative;}
.main-div a .popup-text{display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:-22px;left:0;background:#ccc;padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid #ffffff;}
.popup-text:before {content: "";display: block;background: red;width: 1px;height: 20px;float: left;margin: 0;position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 0px;height: 34px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="social-links">
   <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Facebook">
      <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-20.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Twitter"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-20.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Youtube"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/youtube_circle_color-20.png" alt="Youtube" /></a>
   <a href="javascript:;" data-social="Linkedin"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-20.png" alt="Linkedin" /></a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: **@Haresh Vidya**, there is a problem... I want to do this only if lables are overlapped, not for all :(  can you please help me out?

http://jsfiddle.net/0nxLb3yz/
In given fiddle, first 3 lables are not overlaped, so need to display these at same top value

Comment: Hi Haresh, I know that very well. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: @Reddy, Thanks for understanding, I have got some free time for you.. I have tried to make it as per your expectation as possible as I can.